# What is the model VB.NET sample app?

Tags: vb.net, open-source, desktop-application, sample

I'm looking for an open-source VB.NET app that demonstrates a lot of .NET's power, ideally something that works fully offline. Maybe some of you have encountered an amazing utility app on CodeProject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [VB.NET tag on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?TagName=VB.NET&ProjectSearchText=VB.NET) should keep you going for a while.